# Comments not working in hive CLI

Tags: comments, hive

I have seen other posts saying that double hyphen -- should be a hive comment. But at least within the hive CLI that is not working properly;

```
hive> -- some comment;
FAILED: Parse Error: line 0:-1 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>'
```

Even in Eduardo Capriolo's book he says the same:

```
As of Hive v0.8.0, you can embed lines of comments that start with the string --,
for example:
-- Copyright (c) 2012 Megacorp, LLC.
-- This is the best Hive script evar!
```

The version is apparently 0.8.1 (I am using latest Amazon EMR)

```
hadoop@ip-10-114-113-44:~$ hive
bin is /home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.8.1/bin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a middling workaround:

place semicolon after each comment line like thus:

```
-- some comment  ;
```

Then What happens - the CLI does issue an error (still!) but at least does not mangle the succeeding lines of code.

I am using this technique in a few hive scripts now, it allows me to cut and paste snippets into the CLI (with the mentioned caveat ).

Comment: It doesn't work in my case, what's the blank between "comment" and the colon? A space or "\t"?

Comment: just space(s) . In what sense does it not work? Pls post the error .    btw I think this were my first Q&A in SOF long ago!

Comment: The error in the question keeps occurring.

Answer (score 10):

Case is simple Hive accepts comments but not as a single line. If you try:

```
--comment
show tables;
```

or

```
show tables
--comment;
```

everything will be fine. GL with Hive struggle!

Comment: Generally this is true, but I've found you can't do `--comment[linebreak]SET hivevar:foo=bar;` in the CLI (I guess because `SET` needs to be the start of a statement).  In that case I had to either remove the comment or live with the error from including the semi-colon `--comment;[linebreak]SET hivevar:foo=bar;` (which as javadba points out, is actually a harmless -- if annoying -- error)